# highlight a column

Tags: jquery

I saw in one of the jQuery books where you can highlight a column that's being sorted.

```
$('th.sortable').click(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    var column = $th.index();
    var $table = $th.closest('table');
    var rows = $table.find('tr:not(:has(th))').get();
```

Q: How do I add the 'hightlight' class to every cell in the column that was clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `nth-child` selector which you can use in this case.

```
$('th.sortable').click(function() {
    var $th = $(this),
        column = $th.index(),
        $table = $th.closest('table');

    $table.find('tr td:nth-child(' + (column+1) + ')').addClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd think you'd be able to do something like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4Sg8E/

```
$('th.sortable').click(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.closest('table').find('td:nth-child(' + ($th.index() + 1) + ')')
        .css('background','yellow');
});
```

It will get all `<td>` elements that are the same position as the `<th>` that was clicked, and hilight them.

Comment: You mean `column+1` I think, as you just told me `.index()` was zero-based, while `nth-child` is 1-based. index=0 -> nth-child(1)

Comment: @Harman - Someone else told you index is zero based, and yep, I had it backwards. Already updated.